# Do I have to add LLC every time write my companies name in the same document?

Tags: grammar

I'm working on a quality manual for my company "Joe Blow, LLC"...do I have to use the LLC every time the company name appears in the manual?

Comment: This is a legal question and without researching case law, the answer is 'yes' because you are not writing on a personal level, but a company manual.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following:

> Joe Blow, LLC ("Joe Blow") is a company that welcomes...

And you can simply use "Joe Blow" afterwards. If you really want to go all out:

> Joe Blow, LLC (hereafter "Joe Blow") is a company that welcomes...

Comment: If you want it to falute even higher, use *(**hereinafter** "Joe Blow")*. That's the only use for _hereinafter._